# How to patch value in ReactiveForm

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a form and i am able to get data in "updateData" variable but still not able to patch values in my form

```
checkForUpdate()
  {
    console.log(this.updateData)
    this.myReactiveFormsDialog.patchValue({
      'username' : this.updateData.username,
      'email' : this.updateData.email
    });
  }
```

and while i am passing dummy data for e.g `'username' : 'test'` then its patching

> result of console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
checkForUpdate(){
   console.log(this.updateData)
   this.myReactiveFormsDialog.patchValue(this.updateData[0]);
 }
```

OR

```
checkForUpdate(){
   console.log(this.updateData)
   this.myReactiveFormsDialog.patchValue({
       username: this.updateData[0].username,
       email: this.updateData[0].email
   });
}
```

Comment: username and  email properties are present at  ```zero``` position in array and you are trying without index. See edited answer for more detail.

Comment: well, your updateData is an array (with an unique element) so there are no this.updateData.username, there are this.updateData[0].username